# Error al conectar con la base de datos de Wamp

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Tengo un gran preoblema. Al realizar este codigo:

```html
<?php
require("pagi.html");//pagina en la que esta el formulario
$bd_host="localhost";
$bd_nombre="proyecto";
$bd_usuario="root";
$bd_contra="";
   
$conexion=mysqli_connect($bd_host,$bd_usuario,$bd_contra,$bd_nombre);//coloca los requerimientos para conectar la bds con la pagina web

if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
 echo"error al conectar la base de datos" . mysqly_connect_error($conexion);
 exit();//salir de todo el programa
}

mysqli_set_charset($conexion, "utf8")

$nom_usu=$_GET["Nombre_usuario"];
$ap_usu=$_GET["Apellidos_usuario"];
$tipo_doc=$_GET["tip_doc"];
$num_doc=$_GET["Documento"];
$Correo=$_GET["Correo"];
$Contra=$_GET["Contra"];
$Contra2=$_GET["Contra2"];
$Genero=$_GET["genero"];
$dia_naci=$_GET["dia_nacido"];
$mes_naci=$_GET["mes_nacido"];
$año_naci=$_GET["año_nacido"];

if ($Contra===$Contra2) { 
$ranoia=mysqli_query($conexion, "INSERT INTO registro_usuario(Nombre_usuario,Apellido_usuario,T_documento,N_documento,Correo_usuario,Genero_usuario,dia_nac,mes_nac,año_nac,Contra_usuario,conf_contra) VALUES ('$nom_usu','$ap_usu','$tipo_doc','$num_doc','$Correo','$Genero','$dia_naci','$mes_naci','$año_naci','$Contra','$Contra2')" );
}else{
 echo "Las contraseñas son distintas, revise errores";
  exit();
}

if ($ranoia==false)
 {

echo "error en la consulta" ;
 # code...
}else
{
 echo "se realizo correctamente";
}

mysqli_close($conexion);


?>
```

Al ejecutarlo se acciona la funcion

```
 if ($ranoia==false)
     {

    echo "error en la consulta" ;
        # code...
    }else
    {
        echo "se realizo correctamente";
    }
```

No puede conectar el código con la base de datos, sin embargo no me muestra errores. Es por esto que tuve que realizar esta condición para ver que era lo que provocaba que no llegara la información a la base de datos y no se como solucionarlo. Por favor, ayuda.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

tienes que revisar muy bien los ';' en ti sintaxis el error que tienes es este precisamente.

```
mysqli_set_charset($conexion, "utf8")
```

falta ;

```
mysqli_set_charset($conexion, "utf8");
```

Comment: Gracias, ya logro funcionar.